# Python join strings partially in a list with separator

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings `['what', 'is', 'apple', '&', 'orange']`
Want to do a join only when '&' is in between of two strings.
Wanted:
`['what', 'is', 'apple&orange']`

What I can think of so far looks very dumb
Is there a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: what is dumb about what you have?

Comment: Stack Overflow is generally for fixing problematic code.  Post your code, explain the problem, and we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Here's a 1-liner with string methods

  - [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
  - [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
  - [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```py
l = ['what', 'is', 'apple', '&', 'orange', 'apple', '&', 'banana']

new_list = ' '.join(l).replace(' & ', '&').split()

# print(new_list)
['what', 'is', 'apple&orange', 'apple&banana']
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very pythonic, but it's the cleanest way I could think of. Note that this code breaks if you have an '&' at the last position of your list.

```py
your_list = ['what', 'is', 'apple', '&', 'orange']

out = []
i = 0

while i < len(your_list):
    word = your_list[i]
    
    if (i < len(your_list) - 1) and your_list[i + 1] == '&':
         word = word + '&' + your_list[i + 2]
         i += 2
    
    out.append(word)
    i += 1

print(out)
```

Comment: there's nothing particularly unpythonic about this. Seems pretty clean and straight-forward

Comment: By not pythonic I meant not idiomatic, I mean, it doesn't use any fancy list comprehension or something. But I guess "pythonic" is something very subjective :^)

Comment: Well, no, that's what I'm saying, Pythonic != using list comprehensions anywhere

Comment: Well I guess I need to read Zen of Python again haha

Comment: So, to make it slightly more pythonic, I would do `word = f"{word}&{your_list[i + 2]}"`